# R Optimal way to create time series from start and end dates for groups

Tags: r, survival-analysis, panel-data

I have a data set where for each group I have a start and an end date. I want to turn this data into one where for each time period (month) I have one row of observation for each group.

Here is a sample of input data, groups are identified by id:

```
structure(list(id = c(723654, 885618, 269861, 1383642, 250276, 
815511, 1506680, 1567855, 667345, 795731), startdate = c("2008-06-29", 
"2008-12-01", "2006-09-27", "2010-02-03", "2006-08-31", "2008-09-10", 
"2010-04-11", "2010-05-15", "2008-04-12", "2008-08-28"), enddate = c("2008-08-13", 
"2009-02-08", "2007-10-12", "2010-09-09", "2007-06-30", "2010-04-27", 
"2010-04-13", "2010-05-16", "2010-04-20", "2010-03-09")), .Names = c("id", 
"startdate", "enddate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

I wrote a function and vectorized it. The function takes the three parameters stored in each row and generates the time series with group identifiers.

```
genDateRange<-function(start, end, id){
  dates<-seq(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by="month")
  return( cbind(month=as.character(dates), id=rep(id, length(dates))))
}

genDataRange<-Vectorize(genDateRange)
```

I run the function as follows to get a data frame. I have over 6M lines in the output, so it takes forever. I need a faster way.

```
range<-do.call(rbind,genDataRange(dat$startdate, dat$enddate, dat$id))
```

First ten lines of output looks like this:

```
structure(c("2008-06-29", "2008-07-29", "2008-12-01", "2009-01-01", 
"2009-02-01", "2006-09-27", "2006-10-27", "2006-11-27", "2006-12-27", 
"2007-01-27", "723654", "723654", "885618", "885618", "885618", 
"269861", "269861", "269861", "269861", "269861"), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("month", "id")))
```

I would appreciate a faster way to do this. I think I have focused too much on something and missing a much simpler solution.

Comment: how long is "forever?" how much data do you have

Comment: your first 10 lines of output are not quite right, there should be 2 columns

Comment: .Dim = c(10L, 2L) bit creates two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use the generator function or `rbindlist` because `data.table` can easily handle this without it.

```
# start with a data.table and date columns
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(dat)
dat[,`:=`(startdate = as.Date(startdate), enddate   = as.Date(enddate))]
dat[,num_mons:= length(seq(from=startdate, to=enddate, by='month')),by=1:nrow(dat)]

dat # now your data.table looks like this
#          id  startdate    enddate num_mons
#  1:  723654 2008-06-29 2008-08-13        2
#  2:  885618 2008-12-01 2009-02-08        3
#  3:  269861 2006-09-27 2007-10-12       13
#  4: 1383642 2010-02-03 2010-09-09        8
#  5:  250276 2006-08-31 2007-06-30       10
#  6:  815511 2008-09-10 2010-04-27       20
#  7: 1506680 2010-04-11 2010-04-13        1
#  8: 1567855 2010-05-15 2010-05-16        1
#  9:  667345 2008-04-12 2010-04-20       25
# 10:  795731 2008-08-28 2010-03-09       19

out <- dat[, list(month=seq.Date(startdate, by="month",length.out=num_mons)), by=id]
out 
#          id      month
#   1: 723654 2008-06-29
#   2: 723654 2008-07-29
#   3: 885618 2008-12-01
#   4: 885618 2009-01-01
#   5: 885618 2009-02-01
# ---                  
#  98: 795731 2009-10-28
#  99: 795731 2009-11-28
# 100: 795731 2009-12-28
# 101: 795731 2010-01-28
# 102: 795731 2010-02-28
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009900/is-my-way-of-duplicating-rows-in-data-table-efficient) is related, but the difference is that in you're question we're iterating, not duplicating rows in a data table.

Answer (score 1):

For large datasets this

```
library(data.table)
range <- rbindlist(lapply(genDataRange(dat$startdate, dat$enddate, dat$id),as.data.frame))
```

should be faster than

```
range<-do.call(rbind,genDataRange(dat$startdate, dat$enddate, dat$id))
```